# How to modify the bag file?

Tags: rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I planned to test the result of kinect signal after some information in points cloud is corrupt to simulate the bit error after wireless transmission.

So I firstly save these points could data by rosbag, and I can replay it to rviz project.

However, I then want to change certain bits in the bag file to see what happens when some points data is wrong, and I faced two questions :

1. bag file formate is different from what rosbag-format wiki told?
   I try to make a simple test at first :
   write the publisher always publish Hellow World xxx as the beginner tutorial did, and bag this topic.

   My result bag file looked like this :
   E^@^@^@^P^@^@^@chunk_count=^A^@^@^@^O^@^@^@conn_count=^A^@^@^@^R^@^@^@index_pos=^A&^@^@^@^@^@^@^D^@^@^@op=^C»^O^@^@^R^@^@^@^N^@^@^@Hello World592&^@^@^@   ^@^@^@conn=^@^@^@^@^D^@^@^@op=^B^M^@^@^@time=ahïNlN<9a>1^R^@^@^@^N^@^@^@Hello World593&^@^@^@   ^@^@^@conn=^@^@^@^@^D^@^@^@op=^B^M^@^@^@time=ahïN^Fß<91>7^R^@^@^@^N^@^@^@Hello World594&^

So, I think it should be a plaintext(readable) like something "..etc", but it is not QQ. How can I ask decrypt it to a readable plaintext?

2. After I change the the "Hellow" in the bag file to "ILoveYou", and replay it :
   My subscriber still get the Hello World ........not the ILoveYou World????

This is my first time to use ROS, I have read all overview and done all tutorial in the wiki...
Could anyone give me some suggestion????

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12398/how-to-modify-the-bag-file?/) by [eddyxd](https://answers.ros.org/users/1554/eddyxd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2011-12-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your best bet is to use the [rosbag API](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbag/Code%20API) to try to solve your problem. It gives you access to the bag data so that you can modify it.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-12-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [eddyxd](https://answers.ros.org/users/1554/eddyxd/) on 2011-12-19**:
I has added it but there is a typo, It works now!!! thanks!!

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2011-12-19**:
Did you add  to your manifest.txt?

**Comment by [eddyxd](https://answers.ros.org/users/1554/eddyxd/) on 2011-12-19**:
By the way....I follow the c++ tutorial but get a build msg told me : sniffer.cpp:2:24: error: rosbag/bag.h: No such file or directory, I have set the right path because I can include "ros/ros.h"..@@ could you give me some suggestion?

**Comment by [eddyxd](https://answers.ros.org/users/1554/eddyxd/) on 2011-12-19**:
Thanks!! I think it is what I am looking for!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, all.
I am sorry that I post this thread before I searching this forum....

There is a post teaching a way to convert bag to readable data formate by :
rostopic echo -b file.bag -p /topic

So, my question now is :
How can I convert this readable format back to bag file formate??
(Because I need to changed some bits in it and replay it)

Is it possible?

---

Originally posted by [eddyxd](https://answers.ros.org/users/1554/eddyxd/) with karma: 13 on 2011-12-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1